# C++, CMake, and Xcode Symbol Navigator

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I am creating C++ project that uses CMake to generate a XCode project. It uses the Boost FileSystem with the lines of code

```
  SET(BOOST_ROOT ~/libs/boost/boost_1_64_0)
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.64 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

but now the Symbol Navigator is polluted with thousands of Boost classes

[image: symbol navigator]

Is there any way to exclude these? It's unclear what power I have since my project is generated in cmake. I took a guess and say that my includes were originally `#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"` and changed that to `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` but that doesn't appear to make a difference. Next, I thought there might be a flag on the cmake include directory command so tried `include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` but that didn't work.

Is there a way to indicate that xcode should not include these directories in the navigator?

Comment: (now that I can comment here \o/) Are the boost libraries part of the project : can you see them in the File navigator, under frameworks or something ? How do you link the libraries: by setting link flags in cmake or adding it in Xcode gui ?  Also, did you try creating a new Xcode project with new settings?

Comment: It looks like the problem can be solved using the SYSTEM designator. on include directories (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) while at the same time the old classes _really_ like to hang around so closing Xcode and manually deleting the derived data helps clear out the bad values.

Comment: Also, if the include directory gets mixed in with the path of the project then it assumes it is not system but if you add a directory outside the current source tree / project then it may automatically recognize it as a system directory using both the original and @puio 's  method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filters at the bottom:

- Show only classes and protocols: Click the Classes and Protocols button () in the filter bar at the bottom.
- Show only project symbols: Click the Project Symbols button () in the filter bar at the bottom.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev2241bf769

---

Instead of setting `include_directories`, try setting `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` for the target.

You may need to edit the `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` to make it a space separated string of quoted filepaths.

```
set_target_properties(${target_name} PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/itcaec37c2a6

Comment: I feel like this should work, but Xcode is happily adding all 1410 classes to the project symbols so this flag has limited effect. I suspect it has to do with the `#include` and the cmake addition of the include directory?

Comment: Thanks, so far this has still shows all the symbols when only using the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` attribute. I was hoping that perhaps it was due to a cache so I fiddled with it a bit but so far still seeing everything come in.